# How to stop the Angular Material input counter moving from inside the input to outside on blur?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the newest version of Angular Material Design (1.0.0-rc4). Since updating from 0.11.4, my forms have had a few problems.

Basically, I have two inputs. Before either are focused, the `max-length` counter is displayed inside of the input. After focus, the counter is removed to the bottom of the input, hence changing its height and pushing all inputs down that are below it.

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input md-maxlength="50" required name="title" ng-model="createItem.title">
    <div ng-messages="createItemForm.title.$error" ng-if="createItemForm.title.$touched">
      <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The name has to be less than 50 characters long.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>


  <md-input-container class="md-block extra-margin-top-2">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea ng-model="createItem.description" name="description" columns="3" md-maxlength="500"></textarea>
    <div ng-messages="createItemForm.description.$error" ng-if="createItemForm.description.$touched">
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">The description cannot exceed 500 characters in length.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
```

To replicate the issue, focus on the `Title` input, then unfocus. You will notice that the counter is moved to outside of the input, therefore having the `Description` input pushed down.

How can I stop this from happening? The ideal method would be to never have the counter inside the input, and to always have it underneath (position after blur).

[**Working Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdEeYZ)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div ng-messages="createItemForm.title.$error" ng-if="createItemForm.title.$touched">` makes the container grow.

Since the counter has the CSS property `bottom` set to 7px it will be pulled down once the container grows.

Setting the `top`-property and removing the `bottom`-property does the trick.

`<div class="md-char-counter" style="top: 7px;">0/50</div>`

You can do that with CSS for the class `md-char-counter`, obviously:

```
.md-char-counter {
    bottom:unset;
    top:7px;
}
```

[See working Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaxBaq)